# What's the story behind "St. Wolfgang and the devil" painting?

Tags: satan, saint

I've stumbled upon [this picture](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=saint%20wolfgang%20and%20the%20devil&biw=1325&bih=664&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=Sh5QUJfwKMf4sga82IBY) and got interested.

Is this an episode from St. Wolfgang's life? What's the book that the devil is holding?

Comment: Sorry, not on topic. This is a question about a specific piece of art, not Christianity.

Comment: Perhaps you would like to ask a question about who St. Wolfgang was, what his significance to Christianity is or what his beliefs about the devil were? Asking something along those lines while including a footnote about about looking for any episodes or beliefs that might have led to such a painting might make a decent on topic question. As it is, this is about an artist's work and their conception of something more than it is about Christianity.

Comment: I followed your link to Google images. I clicked one at random. It took me to a Wikipedia page. That page said, "This painting represents the legend of Wolfgang forcing the devil to help him to build a church." This was not exactly difficult.